# UISearchController Swift 4: Spacing Problems

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I'm adding a UISearchController but I keep experiencing spacing problems. In particular, when I conduct a search in the search bar, it shifts up and leaves a black space between the tableview and the search bar.

[image: Initial spacing issues]

Then, when I type the the black space disappears but there's a large white space between the search bar and the table.

[image: Search issues]

I tried adding the following line but the spacing problem becomes worse:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
```

Any helpful hints would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my current code:

```
class SearchViewController: UITableViewController {
var searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
view.isOpaque = false
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: UIBarMetrics.default)

//Set up Table View
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
let searchResultsController = UITableViewController(style: .plain)
searchResultsController.tableView.delegate = self
searchResultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
searchResultsController.tableView.rowHeight = 65
searchResultsController.tableView.register(SearchCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SearchCell")

// Setup  Search Controller
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: searchResultsController)
searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor(red: 34/255, green: 167/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0)
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 34/255, green: 167/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
searchController.searchBar.layer.borderWidth = 1.00

tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
let searchBar = searchController.searchBar
searchBar.sizeToFit()

searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
definesPresentationContext = true
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

Comment: is this happening in all devices?

Comment: Yes, it's happening on all devices.

Comment: @J.Hooper have you got any solution for it? Actually, I also facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try to Add

`self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false`

`self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true`

in viewDidload.

or uncheck "Adjust Scroll View Insets"